# SQL query to compare subsets of rows between each other

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is an SQL query I'm after (in SQL Server). I need to get the count of instances where company Y is more expensive than company X. How would I start to tackle this? I've looked through various examples, but I cannot find anything similiar. I see PARTITION BY could be helpful, but not sure how to start from there - any hint will be very helpful.

```
    ReadingId  |  Product |   Price  |  Company
    ----------------------------------------------
    1          |     A    |    3     |   X
    2          |     A    |    4     |   Y
    3          |     A    |    5     |   Z
    4          |     B    |   11     |   X
    5          |     B    |   12     |   Y
    6          |     B    |   13     |   Z
                                                  ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is conditional aggregation.  For each product:

```
select product,
       max(case when company = 'Y' then price end) as Yprice
       max(case when company = 'X' then price end) as Xprice
from t
group by product;
```

For a count, you can then do:

```
select count(*)
from (select product,
             max(case when company = 'Y' then price end) as Yprice
             max(case when company = 'X' then price end) as Xprice
      from t
      group by product;
     ) p
where Yprice > Xprice;
```

There are other methods as well.  `Pivot` can be used, as well as a `join` with aggregation:

```
select count(*)
from t ty join
     t tx
     on ty.company = 'Y' and tx.company = 'X' and ty.product = tx.product
where ty.price > tx.price;
```

I should point out that all these methods sort of assume that X and Y only appear once for each product.  That seems reasonable given your data.

Answer (score 1):

Rather straight-forward. Get product prices for companies `X` and `Y`. Join them together on product and compare prices.

It assumes that each product is listed once for a company.

```
WITH
CTE_X
AS
(
    SELECT Product, Price
    FROM T
    WHERE Company = 'X'
)
,CTE_Y
AS
(
    SELECT Product, Price
    FROM T
    WHERE Company = 'Y'
)
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cc
FROM
    CTE_X
    INNER JOIN CTE_Y ON CTE_Y.Product = CTE_X.Product
WHERE
    CTE_Y.Price > CTE_X.Price
;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with conditional aggregation.

```
with xandy as (select product, 
               max(case when company = 'X' then price end) as xprice,
               max(case when company = 'Y' then price end) as yprice
               from tablename
               group by product)
select count(*)
from xandy
where yprice > xprice
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT Product
  FROM mytable
  GROUP BY Product
  HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN Company = 'Y' THEN Price END) 
         > 
         MAX(CASE WHEN Company = 'X' THEN Price END) ) AS t
```

The sub-query returns the list of products where company Y is more expensive than company X. The outer query simply counts the number of these products.

Yet another version using a window function:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT Company, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Product 
                            ORDER BY Price DESC) AS rn
  FROM mytable 
  WHERE Company IN ('X', 'Y')) AS t
WHERE t.rn = 1 AND Company = 'Y'
```

The sub-query filters out any rows not having either `'X'` or  `'Y'` as their `Company`. The outer query counts the number of rows for which `Company = 'Y'` has the highest price.

Answer (score 1):

This query, tho not efficient, will give you the details of what you need:

```
Select 
  CompanyY.*,
  CompanyX.*
FROM 
(
  select * from OrderDetails
  where Company = 'Y'
) CompanyY
JOIN
(
  select * from OrderDetails
  where Company = 'X'
) CompanyX
ON CompanyX.Product = CompanyY.Product
WHERE CompanyY.Price > CompanyX.Price
```

**Try the SQLFiddle [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/75170/4/0)**